# android: TimeZone.getDefault() returns EST, not EDT

Tags: java, android, timezone

When I use TimeZone.getDefault() on my phone, I get the wrong time zone (it should be EDT, but it says EST).  When I go into my phone's date and time settings, it says that it's set for EDT.  What am I doing wrong??

This my code:

```
timezone = Calendar.getInstance().getTimeZone()
                                 .getDisplayName(false, TimeZone.SHORT);
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you review [the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/TimeZone.html#getDisplayName%28boolean,%20int%29) for `getDisplayName`, you will find that the first parameter controls whether to return the standard name or the daylight name.  Since you passed `false`, you will always get the standard name.

You can use `inDaylightTime` to determine whether or not the date in question is in daylight time or not.

For example:

```
Date now = new Date();
TimeZone tz = Calendar.getInstance().getTimeZone();
String name = tz.getDisplayName(tz.inDaylightTime(now), TimeZone.SHORT);
```

Answer (score 0):

EDT is a daylight summer time zone, during the winter EST is used instead. So your phone's setting might just display the timezone without taking daylight into account.

Comment: thanks for your help.  I'm still getting EST from this.  This my code:
timezone = Calendar.getInstance().getTimeZone().getDisplayName(false, TimeZone.SHORT);